# dd disk imaging - which conv switches to use and when?

Tags: linux, backup, gzip, dd, diskimage

I will be backing up a large (750GB) disk to an external USB disk using dd.
What is the most appropriate use of `notrunc`, `noerror` and `sync` conversion arguments? It seems some people use them in different ways, or not at all.

Also, what is the best block size? USB is likely to be the bottleneck here.

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | gzip -c > /mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz

gzip -dc /mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `dd`; programs like `ddrescue` have a much better status reporting, imply noerror, and conversion is not desired on disk images at all.

Comment: Good catch. `ddrescue` looks more robust then plain `dd`. Would you use GNU `ddrescue` or `dd_rescue`? What is a good Live CD to download? I would be nice to have GParted + ddrescue + dd + a good collection of drivers on one CD.

Comment: GNU ddrescue has practically superseded Knorr's dd_rescue and also has thankfully done away with requiring an ugly dd_rhelp script.